# How does pgffor foreach and labels work together?

Tags: labels, foreach

I am currently trying to create a label sheet with different bar codes on them.

This is how far I got:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}

%% Change variables here:
\newcommand{\barprefix}{XX}
\newcommand{\barversion}{00}
\newcommand{\baryear}{2017}
\newcommand{\barmonth}{04}
\newcommand{\barstartid}{10}

\newcommand{\bartype}{code128}

% Label format:
\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=8
\LeftPageMargin=7mm
\RightPageMargin=7mm
\TopPageMargin=15mm
\BottomPageMargin=15mm
\InterLabelColumn=2mm
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\LeftLabelBorder=5mm
\RightLabelBorder=5mm
\TopLabelBorder=5mm
\BottomLabelBorder=5mm
\numberoflabels=\LabelCols

\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathparse{subtract(\LabelRows,1)}%
    \pgfmathint{\pgfmathresult}%
    \foreach \n in {0,...,\pgfmathresult}{%
        \pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{3}%
        \pgfmathparse{add(\n,\barstartid)}%
        \pgfmathint{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathdectobase\barid{\pgfmathresult}{10}%
        \genericlabel{%
            \fbox{%
                \begin{pspicture}(0,-0.2)(4.8,1)%
                    \psbarcode{\barprefix\barversion\baryear\barmonth\barid}{includetext includecheck includecheckintext height=0.4}{\bartype}%
                \end{pspicture}%
            }%
        }%
    }
\end{document}
```

The problem with this code is that instead of printing all the labels on one page, it creates a separate page for each row of labels. I can solve this if I just remove the foreach loop and enter every label row via genericlabels myself, but I would like to do this with a for loop so that I just need to change the rows parameter.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: \foreach adds grouping, you can use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` from the pgfplots package instead. Or some other loop command (e.g. `\int_step_variable:nnnNn {0} {1}{\pgfmathresult}{\n}` from expl3 works fine too).

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer that did it!You might want to write an answer for it, so I can vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\foreach` adds grouping.  You can use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` from the pgfplots package instead. Or some other loop command (e.g. `\int_step_variable:nnnNn {0} {1}{\pgfmathresult}{\n}{...}` from expl3 works fine too).